# Upgrade MySQL on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I did an upgrade of my XAMPP from 7.1.24 to 7.4.2. First I uninstall my XAMPP using `uninstall.app`, then I install my new XAMPP, then i check my phpmyadmin everything look ok. But when i open one of my db it said `Table doesn't exists in engine`. I tried to drop the database it said

```
#1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. 
Expected 21, found 20. 
Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100411. 
Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error
```

I search the mysql_upgrade people say just write it on terminal or cmd. I tried it but it say `command not found` then i found people are saying i should do this `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin` on `~/.bash_profile` but the problem is there's no mysql folder on `/usr/local/`. What should i do?
I'm using macOS 10.15.2.

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/1184702 help? That is specifically answering for Ubuntu, but MacOS is similar to Linux in many ways and if XAMPP installs to `/opt` then this answer will probably be the same.

Comment: By the way, that PATH statement didn't work for you because XAMPP doesn't use the same installation directory that the MySQL installer uses.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 11):

(MacOs) I ran mysql_upgrade in the terminal from:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

using:

```
sudo ./mysql_upgrade
```

and it upgraded mysql  be patient at some points it seemed to be stalled but just needs time to complete the upgrade.

Comment: Just works fine

Answer (score 4):

If you are using XAMPP and you can see the XAMPP folder in the applications folder, so you can run this:

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/
sudo mysql_upgrade
```

you should see something like:

```
sudo ./mysql_upgrade
Phase 1/7: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
Phase 2/7: Installing used storage engines... Skipped
Phase 3/7: Fixing views
Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
Phase 5/7: Fixing table and database names
Phase 6/7: Checking and upgrading tables
Processing databases
app
app.areas                                          OK
app.departments                                    OK
app.kiosks                                         OK
Phase 7/7: Running 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES'
OK
```

Note: There appear to be a bug in XAMPP - https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=78386&sid=3d3824dd0b6aa2e33c3adc73c744b4b4

Answer (score 0):

If you get a "command not found" you may look with

```
locate mysql_upgrade
```

where it is.
For me it is

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal app and run `brew upgrade mysql` command, it may help.

If you got the `command not found: brew` it means brew is not installed on your mac and you should install it with this command :

> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

and then retry the first command for upgrading mysql

Comment: If MySQL hasn't been installed using brew in the first place, it could cause problems to do this now